# force app to restart in expo react native

Tags: expo, react-native

My app is created for arabic people ,
and I want to force my app to reload after changing layout to RTL from the first reload ,
this is my code :

```
 if (!I18nManager.isRTL) {
  I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
  await Updates.reloadAsync();
}
```

I'm using expo-updates API ,and I put this code in async function of apploading component , but my app doesn’t reload automatically , I need to close the app manually to RTL take effect , any way to force app to reload or handling RTL support , thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're on expo SDK 38, you can just do `Updates.reload()`, no need to await as well.

This feature was unfortunately removed for SDK 39, but your code should work, just make sure you import from `expo-updates` (if you're using SDK 39)

Answer (score 0):

You can throw a new error to force restart an react native app.

```
throw new Error("Not-an-error: restart")
```

However this won't work inside promises.

Comment: how does this even work? is there a magic word restart? if you are saying this to force crash the app, then it will get caught by error boundary which every proper app should have..

Comment: Yes this is a way to force to reload a react native app. I've included this as the first answer mentioned that `Updates.reload()` is deprecated. Error boundaries does not catch errors for event handlers, async code, errors thrown above the error boundary. The string is a not a magic word, could've been an empty string. I agree that this is an hacky solution and is not meant for enterprise apps, but it still restarts the app, so.

Comment: I think it just crashes the app. this also has to happen outside of error boundary or do special handler within error boundary to work. inside promise, you can bubble up with state but yes this is indeed hacky.